# Django url doesn't match even though it should

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In browser I get:
Request URL:    http://xxxxxx:8000/person/test/

Using the URLconf defined in person.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
`^person/ ^$`
`^person/ ^person/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$`
`^admin/`
The current URL, `person/test/`, didn't match any of these.

In python shell I get:
    `import re`
    `url = 'person/test/'`
    `pattern = re.compile(r'^person/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'`
    `re.match(pattern,url)`
    `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7716860>`

So it obviously should match the regexp.
Using only url person/ (the ^$ regexp) does work.

I've tried restarting the development server of course. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't matching against `r'^person/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'`, the 404 page shows that it's matching against `r'^person/person/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'`

You've probably matched `^person/` in a urls.py, then imported another urls.py and put "person" in there also.  Remove it from the second urls.py.  After importing, a secondary urls.py only has to match the rest of the URL, not the whole URL.

Comment: me only - was missing